# Xcode 9 Simulator slow

Tags: ios, ios-simulator, xcode9

Xcode 9 iOS 11 simulator extremely slow when app is run for the first time. Has anyone experienced the same?
Slow Animations feature of the simulator has already been unchecked.

Answer (score 2):

Yeah, it’s just a bug in `Xcode`

There is a bug in OpenGLES.framework in the iOS 11/tvOS 11/watchOS 4 Simulators that causes them to skip loading the LLVM JIT and fall back to interpreting shaders. This has a severe performance impact on the Simulator since it is entirely software-rendered OpenGL (this includes CoreAnimation, SceneKit, etc).

you need to swap in `OpenGLES.framework` from Xcode 9b3

As a temporary workaround you can copy libCoreVMClient.dylib from Beta 3 into the `Xcode 9 GM` and `xcode 9.0.1`

For iOS this is located at:

```
Xcode[-beta].app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/Library/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot/System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGLES.framework/libCoreVMClient.dylib
```

For tvOS this is located at:

```
Xcode[-beta].app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/AppleTVOS.platform/Developer/Library/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/tvOS.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot/System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGLES.framework/libCoreVMClient.dylib
```

For watchOS this is located at:

```
Xcode[-beta].app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/WatchOS.platform/Developer/Library/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/watchOS.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot/System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGLES.framework/libCoreVMClient.dylib
```

Please check below link:

[Apple Developer Forums](https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/83570?start=0&tstart=0)

[Xcode 9 Simulator is very slow](https://forums.raywenderlich.com/t/new-xcode-9-simulator-is-very-slow/34677)